# Combinatorics: Probability of selecting a a pair of As

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say there are 6 letters: 2 As, 2 Bs, 2 Cs. Say we randomly pair the 6 letters – so 3 pairs of 2. What's the probability that the As get paired together? This is my approach, which is wrong. Why is it wrong?

Say that the letters are A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C3.

Using combinatorics, I see the answer is:

( 1 * (4C2) * (2C2) )/ ( (6C2) * (4C2) * (2C2) ) = 1 / 15

So for the numerator:

- 1 represents the number of ways that A1 can be paired with A2
- 4C2 represents the number of ways that we pair the next 2 balls, out of 4 choices.
- 2C2 represents the number of ways we pair the last 2 balls.

For the denominator:

- 6C2 represents the number of ways that we can choose the first 2 balls to pair
- 4C2 represents the number of ways we can choose the next 2 balls
- 2C2 represents the number of ways we can pair the last 2 balls

**I know the answer should be 1/5. Why am I off by a factor of 3?**

Answer (score 6):

In the denominator, A1 can be in any of the three pairs. In the numerator, A1 can only be in the first pair considered. Make these consistent and you will avoid the factor of $3$.

For example, if you require A1 to be in the first pair in the denominator, your calculation becomes $$\dfrac{ (\,^1C_1) \times (\,^4C_2) \times (\,^2C_2)}{  (\,^5C_1) \times (\,^4C_2) \times (\,^2C_2) } = \dfrac15$$
and if A1 can be in any of the three pairs then $$\dfrac{ (\,^3C_1) \times (\,^1C_1) \times (\,^4C_2) \times (\,^2C_2)}{  (\,^6C_2) \times (\,^4C_2) \times (\,^2C_2) } = \dfrac15$$ and both match the correct intuitive idea that A1 can be matched with any of the five other letters with equal probability, one of which is the desired A2.

Comment: Why do you have 5C1 in the denominator?

Comment: @EricAldrin Because any one of the five other letters can be paired with A1 in the denominator while only the desired one can be paired with A1 in the numerator

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which will give the correct answer easily is to visualise three pairs of slots $\square\square\;\;\square\square\;\;\square\square$ and just place the $A's$

The first $A$ can be put *anywhere*, and then the second $A$ has just one appropriate place in $5$ vacant, thus $Pr = \Large\frac15$